# How to block the code until the event handler C#

Tags: c#, winforms, events, delegates, async-await

I'm looking for a method to block my code until a event handler is runned.

My code is like below :

```
private void extendBt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DisplayPrompt("Select a Construction line (L) or Two point (P) to extend");

    // I want this code is blocked here, then user must press on P or L to continue

    this.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(keypressed); 

    if (key == "p")
    {
        // Method "P";
    }
    if (key == "l")
    {
        // Method "L";
    }
    else // If L or P aren't pressed => How to return to the select event on keyboard  ?
}
```

Comment: If I understand it correctly, just move the rest of method into `keypressed` event handler.

Comment: Trying to block the UI thread is always going to produce deadlock, no point in trying to pursue that solution.  This ought to not be hard to do another way, simply add a *bool* variable to your form and set it to *true* in the Click event handler.  Now your KeyPress event handler knows what to do.  Do keep in mind that KeyPress is raised on the control that has the focus, that will not be your form.  Surely the real problem you are trying to solve.  Override ProcessDialogChar() instead.

Comment: Convert to Async Await, implement TaskCompletionSource and await on the Task

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i'am an amateur in programmation in C# so i don't understand the most of your reponse :D

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a windows forms based application based on the `KeyPressEventHandler`.

From a user interface design POV, the form should have a `RadioButton` or `Combobox` so user can make the selection. Until that is done, disable the extend button.

If you want to stick to this way, you will need to create another form and put the selection controls there. On the button click, display that CustomForm using `ShowDialog` and when user selects, based on that, return a `DialogResult` to main form. You can choose yes/no for P/L and then process accordingly.

You do not need `KeyPressEventHandler` at all then.

Comment: Thanks for your reponse, i can do it with a second form (this form appears with 2 buttons) but i want to try in another way to learn.

Comment: @MDN This way is not going to work as the click event handler is blocking the UI thread. No further user actions on this form will captured until click event handler is done.

Answer (score -1):

Well you dont Need to disable the Event if p ore l Arent pressed, because Nothing will happen than.

But if you rly want to disable it use following Code:

```
    private void extendBt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         DisplayPrompt("Select a Construction line (L) or Two point (P) to extend");

         // I want this code is blocked here, then user must press on P or L to continue

          this.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(keypressed); 

         if (key == "p")
         {
             // Method "P";
         }
         if (key == "l")
         {
             // Method "L";
         }
        else 
        {
             this.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(keypressed); 
        }    
    }
```